# JSON error when compiling Flex file with MXMLC

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, mxml, mxmlc

tI have a file create with Flash Builder and the Flex 4.1 SDK which compiles fine in Flash Builder 4.5.1 but fails to compile with the command-line MXMLC (run via SublimeText 2 build system file).  It doesn't like this line:

`var dataString:String = JSON.encode(packagedData);`

with the error

`Error: Access of undefined property JSON.`

I realize what the error means, but why does in work inside Builder but not in the command line?  Is there a library I need to include if I'm building it this way?

Comment: JSON Wasn't added to the Flash Player until after Flex 4.1 was released.  You'll probably have to update the PlayerGlobals and/or AIR SDK of your SDK if you want to use JSON.  It'll be easier to just use a more recent SDK, such as Flex 4.6 or Apache Flex 4.8 .

Comment: Why does it compile and work fine when compiled via Flash Builder 4.5.1 (using the 4.1 sdk as a build target)?

Comment: Perhaps because it is targeting another FlashPlayer version. Maybe FB adds the correct PlayerGlobal.swc to the build path when you select a specific player version.

Comment: JSON is specific to FP11+  I bet in FB, FP11 is selected as player target, so make sure you manually tell the compiler to target player 11 and it should work fine

Comment: pardon my ignorance, but when issuing the mxmlc command how do I target a player version?

Comment: swf-version=int [See this doc on how to use it](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html) or target-player [See this doc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ee0.html)